# miktex installation error: make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop

Tags: makefile, ubuntu-14.04, configure, miktex

I am trying to install **miktex** on Ubuntu 14.04. I am following the instructions at http://miktex.org/howto/build-unx. But when I type the command `make`, the following error is shown:

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

I tried the command `./configure`, but it resulted in the following error:

```
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

Anyone knows how to solve it??

Comment: What command did you use before `make`?

Comment: `confugre` is not `configure`.

Comment: The command used before `make` was:  `cmake -G "Unix Makefiles"`

Comment: That was a spelling mistake, I tried `./configure` only @user657267